# Have there been any practical applications devised for the observation that copper rapidly inactivates coronaviruses?

Tags: environmental-conditions, coronavirus

A 2015 [study](https://mbio.asm.org/content/6/6/e01697-15) reported that

> We have shown previously that noroviruses are destroyed on copper alloy surfaces. In this new study, **human coronavirus 229E was rapidly inactivated on a range of copper alloys (within a few minutes for simulated fingertip contamination)** and Cu/Zn brasses were very effective at lower copper concentration. Exposure to copper destroyed the viral genomes and irreversibly affected virus morphology, including disintegration of envelope and dispersal of surface spikes. Cu(I) and Cu(II) moieties were responsible for the inactivation, which was enhanced by reactive oxygen species generation on alloy surfaces, resulting in even faster inactivation than was seen with nonenveloped viruses on copper. Consequently, copper alloy surfaces could be employed in communal areas and at any mass gatherings to help reduce transmission of respiratory viruses from contaminated surfaces and protect the public health.

A more recent [study](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMc2004973) (published March 17) on SARS-CoV-2 found among other things (as [reported](https://www.straitstimes.com/world/united-states/coronavirus-covid-19-bug-can-persist-in-air-for-hours-and-on-surfaces-for-days) in the press)

> On plastic and stainless steel, viable virus could be detected after three days.
>
> On cardboard, the virus was not viable after 24 hours.
>
> On copper, it took four hours for the virus to become inactivated.

Have these observations about copper been used/incorporated in any public health measures (not necessarily relating to the COVID-19 outbreak)?

Comment: @CareyGregory: No problem. My guess is that copper toxicity could be an obstacle to making practical use of this finding. I see that they do mention a clincal trial at the very end of their discussion section https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4561453/

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer, but refernces of these wikipedia pages could start you into literature https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimicrobial_copper-alloy_touch_surfaces https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kupfer#Bakterizide_Eigenschaften

Comment: I should replace all my door handles with brass ones!

Comment: @GrahamChiu: I propose [a different application](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/90883/why-are-victims-of-covid19-being-wrapped-in-plastic/90914#comment162139_90914) :p

Comment: Interesting that tarnished brass is still effective

Comment: @GrahamChiu: in that respect "at a lower percentage of copper, the cartridge brass was far superior to copper nickel C71500, inactivating virus in approximately one-third the time" so apparently anything with nickel (stainless steel has it too) is actually helping viruses survive more somehow.

Comment: Copper toxicity is negligible; water pipes are commonly made of copper, and they rarely cause copper toxicity.